# How to change the permission and ownership for internal sdcard

Tags: root-access, permissions, troubleshooting

I have a problem with my internal SD card on my android 4.2.2. It shows there are no files on the internal SD card but there is a shortcut called "legacy" and I can't write anything on the internal SD card or download on it but I can install apps on it.

I found on Root Explorer that the `owner` and `group` is set to root. I try to change to system but it does not change.

And the permissions is set to read and execute for the `owner` and `group` and `other`. 
The write permissions is disabled to the `owner` and `group` and `other`.
I also try to change the permissions and unroot my phone but it does not work.

Is there any solution for my problem?

Comment: Did you tried formatting the whole SD card using your PC ???

Comment: Open the `legacy` folder, the contents of your SD card are (usually) there.

Comment: Yes i tried to format the sdcard but the problem still exist

Comment: I try to enter the internal storage on my pc and there is no files or folders

Comment: And my pc set to show hidden and system items

Comment: I found on root explorer that the owner and group is set to root and I try to change the values to system but it does not change